# jQuery progressbar not filling properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I'm using signalr to broadcast % complete for a long running process and jQuery to update a progressbar and also display an item count x of x. Area-valuenow of the progress bar is updated as expected, but I cannot figure out how to get the bar to progress while also keeping the border fixed at 100% width.

Basically, the progressbar border AND fill width increase together, instead of just the fill. Does that make sense? I've tried feeding the width value to the span instead of the div, but when I do, nothing happens. Additionally, my bar is progressing in both directions!

What am I doing wrong here?

```js
    function progress(pctDone, imported, rowCount) {
        $('#progress-bar')
            .progressbar({value: pctDone})
            .text(imported + " of " + rowCount);
        $('#progress-bar').css('width', pctDone + '%');
    }
```

```css
.progressbar {
  background-color: #86b5e1;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.progressbar span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="progressbar" id="progress-bar" >
  <span style="width: 0%"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to add `$` on `('#progress-bar')`.
JsFiddle:
[here](https://jsfiddle.net/zbLf422q/)

Comment: Sorry, it was a copy/paste fail when I created this post. My code has the $

Answer (score 0):

Hi check this it will be useful to you  http://jsfiddle.net/neodescorpio/NAs3V/

if you dont wants to run 100 % just replace the function

```
 function progress() {
           progressbar.progressbar("value", 50);
      }
```

so inside u can specify your own value